# Facebook Like Button (<fb:like>) Height Always 80px

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

Why is the height of my Facebook Like button (technically the iframe that gets generated) always getting set to 80px? Example page is here: http://www.davidkasper.net/test.html I am using the javascript sdk and have had it work on other pages but for some reason the height will not change dynamically on this one! I can even do something like
`<fb:like style="height:40px">`
 and that will indeed set the visible height, but the iframe will still be 80px, whereas I can see it changing in the demo at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer for this!!

The problem was having the wrong base domain set for the app that I specified in the FB.init javascript.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '**131226520233112**', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
```

See the difference between http://davidkasper.net/test.html vs http://davidkasper.net/test2.html

By the way I would never have discovered this without the URL Linter from Facebook http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ Clearing all the errors it detected solved the problem!

Answer (score 4):

The iframe being generated is allowing space for showing facebook profile pictures. Add the show-faces="false" attribute and it will collapse the height.

```
<fb:like show-faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 2):

I fix this problem with css

```
#fb-bar iframe{min-height:80px !important;}
```

where #fb-bar is wrapper for < fb:like >. In html

```
<div id="fb-bar">
  <fb:like href="link"></fb:like>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

David,

I was having the same problem too. I simply put the fb:like tag inside of a DIV with an ID of 'facebook-like'. Then I setup a CSS rule to limit the height and/or width of any iframe that exists in the 'facebook-like' DIV. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

From the reference it says

> The most important social plugin is
>   the Like button, which enables users
>   to post pages from your site back to
>   their Facebook profile with one click.
>   You can add a Like button to any page
>   with an iframe tag:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=http://example.com"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

> There are a number of options for the
>   Like button, including the option to
>   include the names and profile pictures
>   of the user's friends who have also
>   liked the page. Here is a like button
>   for the Facebook Developers site...

To me that indicates you should just use the iframe and set the width/height properties in the style tag...

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=http://example.com"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:300px; height:25px"></iframe>
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to use the XFBML version because it needs to resize dynamically depending on whether there are faces or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Uncheck the 'Show Faces' checkbox. This will reduce the height to 35px.